# Temperature Tower came out too good

Tags: print-quality, g-code, calibration

I've switched to a PLA of a different color and wanted to figure out what temperature my nozzle should be so I printed a temperature tower. However, the towers came out perfect and the only stringing was from the last bit of plastic oozing out when the print head moved to X-home.

I loaded the tower stl file in Ultimaker Cura and did the post processing script to change the temperature from 240 °C at layer 1 (changing from 200 for the skirt). And decreasing the temp by 10 degrees every segment after. Here is the resulting print vs the expected print:
[image: Actual Temperature Tower][image: Expected Temperature Tower]

I was expecting an over-extruded, blobby mess and stringing to make a spider feel at home towards the bottom, but this is one of my best prints yet.

I watched the print in its entirety and the printer was set to the respective temperatures and the nozzle reached them, as confirmed by OctoPrint:
[image: OctoPrint Temp Graph]

And the G-Code does have post processing scripts generated by Ultimaker Cura:
[image: G-Code]

Any ideas why my print looks so good? I'm printing PLA at various nozzle temps, 60 °C on bed with the Creality CR-10S sliced with Ulitmaker Cura 3.6.0.

Comment: Shouldn't there be bridges between the two columns at each level?

Comment: Not in this particular model. However uploaded images of the print show that globbing doesn't necessitate the bridges. I'll see if I find an image.

Comment: Added an image showing what I was expecting from the maker of the model.

Comment: Your material works well at a larger temperature range than expected. What was the problem?

Comment: I'm under the impression that 220 °C is extremely high for PLA let alone 240 °C.  Have a hit the lottery with this filament then?

Comment: Temperature is not the only thing that affects stringing, so perhaps your mix of slicer setting (retraction, wipe, not traversing over outlines, etc) are perfect.

Comment: Try changing the fan speed and do another one: maybe you can improve the quality at high temperature. Below 220 you won't get optimal layer strength.